# C# Matching game, only can turn cards around when I first show a messagebox

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a little trouble with my matching game. Whenever I click the second card, it only will turn around the second card when I first show a messagebox.
I've tried many things but only the messagebox seems to fix the issue.
Edit: changed Thread.Sleep() to Delay() function.

```
    private bool Delay(int millisecond)
    {

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        bool flag = false;
        while (!flag)
        {
            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > millisecond)
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        return true;

    }



        private Image card1; //first card
    private Image card2; //second card
    private void CardClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Image card = (Image)sender; 
        ImageSource front = (ImageSource)card.Tag;
        card.Source = front; //turns card.

        if (this.card1 == null)
        {
            //store card in card1, check if its already turned.
            this.card1 = card;
        }
        else
        {
            this.card2 = card;

            MessageBox.Show("kb"); //only works when THIS msgbox is shown.

            //check if same if so: dont turn around again, otherwise turn around.
            string imageTag = Convert.ToString(this.card1.Tag);
            string imageFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageTag);
            string image2Tag = Convert.ToString(this.card2.Tag);
            string imageFileName2 = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image2Tag);
            if (imageFileName != imageFileName2)
            {
                bool del = Delay(800);

                //turn images back.
                card1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/MemoryCardDesign/CLcards/bck.png", UriKind.Relative));
                card2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/MemoryCardDesign/CLcards/bck.png", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Match");
                //check turn IF multiplayer, and give points to player
            }


            this.card1 = null;
            this.card2 = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep()`. Use a timer instead.

Comment: @itsme86 I've done that, but it's still not showing the second card without the messagebox. Nevertheless, thanks for your advise

Comment: What does your code look like with the timer?

Comment: @itsme86 I've updated the post, I now use Stopwatch

Comment: I meant an actual timer. There are timers you can use that will invoke a method when the time has elapsed.